# How to override response headers in ASP.NET Web Api using MediaTypeFormatter

Tags: asp.net, csv, asp.net-web-api, response-headers, mediatypeformatter

I'm currently developing a MediaTypeFormatter to process a csv files from a Web Api Controller. How can I add the 
contentHeaders.Add("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=filename.csv");

As of now, I have the following code, but the content-disposition header is ignored. I would like provide a link such that presents the user with the save dialod. eg. /api/students?format=csv

```
public class ServiceStackCSVFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{

    public ServiceStackCSVFormatter()
    {            
        //this.AddQueryStringMapping("format","csv", "text/csv");
        this.AddQueryStringMapping("format", "csv", "text/html"); 
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv"));         
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("type");

        return true;
    }

    public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        content.Headers.Clear();
        content.Headers.Add("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=result.csv");          
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CsvSerializer.SerializeToStream(value, writeStream));
        return task;
    }

    public override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, System.Net.Http.HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
    { 
        var task = Task<object>.Factory.StartNew(() => CsvSerializer.DeserializeFromStream(type, readStream));
        return task;
    }
    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you currently have is too late to modify the headers (headers are sent first and then the body). You can override the method called `SetDefaultContentHeaders` to modify the outgoing headers.